# Django React with i18n

Tags: django, reactjs, internationalization

Wondering what is the best practices to use django with React when i18n needed.

Currently I'm loading javascript_catalog on global scope.
all the translations controlled by django i18n.

From react components I'm using gettext django javascript catalog function to translate all the necessary texts.

For localization i'm also using django i10n support provided by javascript_catalog.

anyone have better practices for this using i18n in both django and react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not claim this is best practice but it works for me. Separating the frontend and backend a bit.

Think about it, what part translation is related to ? UI/UX right ?

Therefore, why have it on the backend, why not just have it in your react project ?

Steps: install i18next for react:

```
npm install react-i18next@legacy i18next --save
```

Notice, you will not get a > v9 but this tutorial :
https://react.i18next.com/legacy-v9/step-by-step-guide

is still valid,

step 1:
create translation folder in your src folder like this:

```
 -src
    -translations
      -ar
        transilationsAR.js
      -en 
        transilationEN.js
      - i18n.js
   - App.js
```

The way I do it, is manually to insure amazing User experience.
This code will turn any keywords From ENGLISH-ENGLISH to any language:
data_pre.py

```
en_en= {"kw": "kw"}
en_kw = []
for kw in en_en:
    en_kw.append(kw)
# translate the list of english kw to desired language via google translate
ar_kw = """ [en_to_desired_langauge] """
ar_kw = ar_kw.replace("،", ",")
ar_kw = eval(ar_kw)
en_ar = dict()
for i in range(0, len(ar_kw)):
    en_ar[en_kw[i]] = ar_kw[i]
# en_ar key words are in en_ar variable.
```

transilationEN.js : Here we will have for example ENGLISH-ENGLISH keywords dictionary,
there are some tools help you fetch all key words, phrases from your website.

```
export const TRANSLATIONS_EN = {
  'Hello': 'Hello',
}
```

transilationAR.js, here we have new dictionary out of data preprocessing.

```
export const TRANSLATIONS_AR = {
  'Hello': 'مرحبا',
}
```

run

```
npm install --save i18next-browser-languagedetector
```

i18n.js

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import {TRANSLATIONS_AR } from "./ar/translationsAR";
import { TRANSLATIONS_EN } from "./en/translationsEN";

// the translations
// (tip move them in a JSON file and import them)
const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: TRANSLATIONS_EN
  },
  ar: {
    translation: TRANSLATIONS_AR
  },
};

i18n
  .use(initReactI18next) 
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .init({
    resources,
    lng:[ "en", 'ar'],

    keySeparator: false, 

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false 
    },
    react: {
      useSuspense: false
    }
  });

export default i18n;
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import i18n from "./translations/i18n";
class App extends Component {
    handleChangeLangToAR = () => {
      i18n.changeLanguage("ar")
  };

  handleChangeLangToEN = () => {
    i18n.changeLanguage("en")
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <SomeComponent
              {...this.props}
              handleChangeLangToAR={() => this.handleChangeLangToAR()}
              handleChangeLangToEN={ () => this.handleChangeLangToEN()}
              />
  

    );
  }
}


export default (withTranslation()(App));
```

now in someComponent.js we have acess to t() via props, which can be use to translate any keywords, phrases on our website.

someComponent.js

```
import React from "react";

class someComponent extends React.Component {
   render() {
      const { handleChangeLangToEN, handleChangeLangToAR, t} = this.props;
      return (
         
         <h1>{t('Hello')}</h1>


)
}
};

export default someComponent();
```

handleChangeLangToEN: can be set to onClick on a button to switch site language to English.

handleChangeLangToAR : can be set to onClick a button to switch site language to Arabic.

Both sould be in layout component, so we do not have to pass them every where in our project.

for example:

```
<Button OnClick={ () => handleChangeLangToEN }> English </Button>
```

Or if we have another component we want to translate, simply we export the component with WithTranslation , then we have access to t():

anotherComponent.js

```
import React from "react";
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
class anotherComponent extends React.Component {
   render() {
      const {t} = this.props;
      return (
         
         <h1>{t('Hello')}</h1>


)
}
};
export default (withTransilation()anotherComponent)
```

if you are connecting your props using redux store an still would like to use withTransilation(), do not get confused, you do it like this.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.token !== null
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onTryAutoSignup: () => dispatch(actions.authCheckState())
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(withTranslation()(App));

'''
```